# Ubuntu auto-detect Nvidia driver version for install

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I used this code to install the Nvidia driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa                
sudo apt update             
sudo apt install nvidia-384
```

**Problem:** There are many versions available. How do I choose the right one? Is there any way to auto-detect the right version based on the hardware?

Comment: The way is using geforce.com or nvidia.com to check the driver versions supporting your specific hardware. Then, if one of the listed drivers is already provided by the official repositories for your Ubuntu release, just install, no need for a PPA. Otherwise, you may add that PPA and install from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This should recommend the right driver.