# Not able to use propietary nvidia drivers properly on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, 21.04

My laptop has Nvidia Geforce 920M but it was not getting detected on Ubuntu 21.04 when nouveau open source drivers were set. Today I installed propietary tested drivers(nvidia-driver-460) through command line and rebooted and then my gpu was detected. But with these drivers, I am facing a problem. If I put my laptop to suspend mode, it does not wake up properly. There is only a blank screen and an underscore symbol. I have to restart my laptop.

After I faced this issue, I changed the drivers to nouveau opensource again and there is no such issue of not waking up there. But with these opensource drivers, my graphics card is not getting detected.

Comment: So what is the problem you have a driver and it works? Please clarify.

Comment: When I use proprietary driver, the laptop does not wake up from suspend mode. I have to restart it every time.

Comment: I repeat it works why are you trying to change the driver you have not given a reason.

Comment: With nouveau opensource drivers, my graphics card is not getting detected. And with the proprietary ones, my laptop does not wake up from suspend mode. I need my Nvidia card to work, that's why I am changing drivers. Now understood my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed nvidia-driver-390 for my geforce 920M by typing `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390` in the terminal and now I don't have any issue.

EDIT: Few softwares gave an error that nvidia-driver-390 was too old and I needed a newer version to make them work properly, so I started testing some other drivers for my GPU and found that nvidia-driver-418-server is also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/149138/en-us), you are using the wrong driver version for your particular card.

Run the following commands to ensure proper installation and configuration of the correct proprietary driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Still, the Nvidia website does have some contradictions:  the 430 driver is what the search tools comes up with, yet the 465.10 driver claims support of the (EOL 4/19) 920M https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/102072/.

Comment: That autoinstall command also installs nvidia-driver-460 and the same issue occurs. I also installed the recommended nvidia-driver-430 manually but unfortunately the same issue occured again. Then I  started testing different proprietary drivers and finally found nvidia-driver-390 working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Aviral That's good. You can write an answer to your own question to help others who have the same issue. Then, you can mark your answer as the accepted solution after a couple of days.

Comment: @ubfan1 I think that's because that is the 465.10 Windows driver. The [Nvidia 460 for linux](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/167671/en-us) shows support for the 920MX but not the 920M.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the nvidia ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and then installing the drivers as shown [here](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_nvidia_ppa/).

[Also](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035595/226614)

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

can recommend a driver.